# Can not get data with error 400 bad request

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to get data by passing id to the API.

```
    const id = useParams();
    console.log(id);

    const [posts, getPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOnePost();
    }, []);

    const getOnePost = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${id}`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allPost=response.data.onePost;
                getPosts(allPost);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(posts);
```

This is the code I wrote to do the task. I get the Id from the URL and it prints successfully. When I test this by using postman in the backend then it also works correctly. But I run this code in the front end I cannot print posts because the error says 400 (bad request).

[image: This is a screenshot of error]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: A screenshot would be more expressive. There could be a lot of reasons for a 400 error. 4xx error codes typically mean there is an error in user authentication (session or token).

Comment: @Romit I will add a screenshot of the error that I got.

Comment: Looks like `id` is not a number, rather an object

Comment: @TJ What is the reason for that. Is there any wrong with getting id using ` const id = useParams()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useParams will be returning object. So you have to modify the first line in your code as

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

I believe this will solve your issue